# How to fold / collapse the first comment block on file load?

Tags: comment, code-folding

Is there a way to fold the first comment of a file on load?

While I don't like code folding in general, it can be handy in this one instance when every file has a boiler plate header which isn't useful to see each time.

Is there a way to setup emacs to do this?

*I'm not looking for an advanced code-folding feature, just the most simple code folding, with a way to see the first comment if it's needed.*

Comment: Almost duplicate of [Hide long copyright message at top of all files
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923459/hide-long-copyright-message-at-top-of-all-files)

Comment: AFAIK answers on other sites aren't considered duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I use [elide-head.el](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/elide-head.el) (which comes with Emacs) specifically for this purpose.

### Setup

Add the following to your `init.el`.

```
;; enable elide-head to hide boilerplate
(require 'elide-head)
;; automatically enable it for CC-mode's languages
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'elide-head)
```

### Result

By default `elide-head` understands GNU, BSD, and X11 preambles. So, with the above initialization, whenever you load a C/C++ file, the display of your code could go from something like this:

```
/**
 *  $Id: main.cc 2993 2011-11-11 01:11:11Z you $
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1969
 *  you <you@yousjob.cc>
 *  Some "Other" Author
 *  Some "Dude Who Didn't Really" Help
 *  and Bunch of Fools <http://yousjob.cc/fools/>
 *
 *  This file is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
 *
 */
```

To:

```
/**
 *  $Id: main.cc 2993 2011-11-11 01:11:11Z you $
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1969
 *  you <you@yousjob.cc>
 *  Some "Other" Author
 *  Some "Dude Who Didn't Really" Help
 *  and Bunch of Fools <http://yousjob.cc/fools/>
 *
 *  This file is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify...
 *
 */
```

### Customization

The above is enough for me as I often want to <s>curse</s>praise who was there before me, but you could tighten things up if you wanted. Continuing with our example, if you changed your `elide-head` setup to:

```
;; enable elide-head to hide boilerplate
(require 'elide-head)
(add-to-list 'elide-head-headers-to-hide 
             '("Copyright (C)" . "If not, see <http://www\\.gnu\\.org/licenses/>\\.?"))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'elide-head)
```

whenever you loaded a C/C++ file your code would look like:

```
/**
 *  $Id: main.cc 2993 2011-11-11 01:11:11Z you $
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1969...
 *
 */
```

`elide-head-headers-to-hide` is an alist of regexp pairs that mark the start and end of the area that you want to elide. [Read the source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/elide-head.el) for complete details. [`elide-head.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/elide-head.el) is less than 120 lines.

### Another option

The comments in `elide-head.el` note that [`hs-minor-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow) can act similarly, but is not as selective, which maybe something that you want.